# I want the html obtained from the text area to run in the browser's new tabb.Is that possible?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Can I run html in a variable in a new tab?

example:

I want the html obtained from the text area to run in the browser's new tab.
Is that possible?

```
$('body').on('click', '.excute_html_button', function (e) {
    const id = this.id;
    const html = $("#title-area-"+id).val()

    // is it possible?
    // new tab open and execute html
});
```

Either vanilla JS or jQuery.

example html vue code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Getting Started</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      {{ message }}
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          message: 'Hello Vue.js'
        }
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You told me the answer, but I still have a problem ^^;

vue code
There is a problem that the html is output as it is.
{{text}}

Maybe it's because the code ran inside the body

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open a new window or tab using `window.open`, save a reference to the opened window, then assign to the `innerHTML` of its document:

```
$('body').on('click', '.excute_html_button', function (e) {
    const id = this.id;
    const html = $("#title-area-"+id).val()
    const w = window.open();
    w.document.body.innerHTML = html;
});
```

The user may have popup blockers, in which case you'd want to check if the window exists first, and display a message to the user if it couldn't be opened:

```
$('body').on('click', '.excute_html_button', function (e) {
    const id = this.id;
    const html = $("#title-area-"+id).val()
    const w = window.open();
    if (!w) {
      console.error("Window couldn't be opened, please permit popups from this site for full functionality");
      // or put the above message into an HTML element
      return;
    }
    w.document.body.innerHTML = html;
});
```

This may open a new tab *or* it may open a new window, IIRC, it depends on the user's browser settings, and isn't something Javascript can choose between.

To include Javascript and Vue, you won't be able to execute scripts by changing the `innerHTML`. Instead, you have to insert the `<script>` tag using `document.createElement('script')` - first insert Vue, wait for it to load, then insert the new script tag with other Javascript that invokes it:

```
const w = window.open();
const html = `<div id="app">
  <button @click="disabled = (disabled + 1) % 2">Toggle Enable</button>
  <input type="text" :disabled="disabled == 1">

  <pre>{{ $data }}</pre>
</div>`;
w.document.body.innerHTML = html;
const script = w.document.body.appendChild(w.document.createElement('script'));
script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js";
script.onload = () => {
  w.document.body.appendChild(w.document.createElement('script')).textContent = `
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      disabled: 0,
    },
  });`;
};
```

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/dvumwxfo/

Comment: However, in the case of vue code, {{mytext}} is printed. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: You'll have to (1) load the Vue library: `w.document.body.appendChild(w.document.createElement('script')).src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"` and (2) call `new Vue` inside the new window `w.document.body.appendChild(w.document.createElement('script')).textContent = 'new Vue({ ...'`

Comment: thanks for CertainPerformance but is it necessary to configure vue instance manually in vue html? Is there any other way? I want one shot ^^;

Comment: See edit, if you want to run scripts as well, you can't use `.innerHTML`, you have to create the script elements explicitly instead

Comment: It's a little difficult for me
But I'll try it right away Thank you for the perfect answer